# Ruby / Rails: How do I display the sum value per year and month?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called Receipt and it has the following:

- date_of_purchase - datetime
- total_value - float

I have a database that contains many receipts, for example:

Receipt 1

- date_of_purchase = 2012-01-23
- total_value = 6

Receipt 2

- date_of_purchase = 2012-01-04
- total_value = 70

Receipt 3

- date_of_purchase = 2013-02-14
- total_value = 1.23

Receipt 4

- date_of_purchase = 2013-02-06
- total_value = 90.34

...

Receipt 123

- date_of_purchase = 2013-08-05
- total_value = 43.69

How do I display something like this:

{2012=>{1=>76}, 2013=>{2=>92.23, 3=> 34.43, ...}}

?

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: I just know how to do grouping but not sum and grouping by year and month.

Answer (score 1):

Following should work

```
receipts = Receipt.find_by_sql("SELECT MONTH(date_of_purchase) AS month, 
                       YEAR(date_of_purchase) AS year, SUM(total_value) as sum
                       FROM receipts GROUP BY year, month")

receipts_hash = {}
receipts.each do |receipt|
  receipts_hash[receipt.year] = {} unless receipts_hash[receipt.year]
  receipts_hash[receipt.year][receipt.month] = receipt.sum
end
```

Comment: It returned a bunch of elements instead:

=> [#<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >, #<Receipt >]

Comment: Check for `receipts_hash`